# How to remove the all elements from Array in React

Tags: reactjs, arrays, react-redux

I have the array with ids

```
const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState<readonly string[]>([]);
var selectedId = props.selectedId;
```

When clicking on the clean button I have added a useState() which check the given selectedId has a value or not
If selectedId has a value then add a value in array, if not then remove all the elements from the array

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (selectedId != undefined) {  
            // Add selectedId in selectedIdsList
            setSelected(selectedId)
        } else {
            // remove all elements from setSelected
        }
    }, [selectedId]);
```

How to delete all elements from array

Comment: `selectedIdsList ` isn't array it is object

Comment: @VishalBeep i have updated the code please check

Comment: to delete or empty an array do something like this `selectedIdsList = []` but since you are using state you can set it something like this = `setSelected([])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete all elements inside array or empty an array we can do something like this
`selectedIdsList = []` but since you are using state you can set it something like this

```
 setSelected([]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reassign the array to an empty array
selectedIdsList = []

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you should write setSelected([])